# Get source port and packets/bytes counters from Azure AzureNetworkAnalytics_CL

Tags: azure, logging, kql, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I am trying to get flow data on an Azure application using KQL AzureNetworkAnalytics_CL.

1. In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/traffic-analytics-schema?tabs=nsg) there is no field for the source port, it is a mandatory field for my solution (5-touple based), is there anyway to get it?
2. Kusto query failed to return PacketsDestToSrc, PacketsSrcToDest, BytesDestToSrc and BytesSrcToDest.

I tried the following Java code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String kustoQuery = "AzureNetworkAnalytics_CL | project TimeGenerated, SrcIP_s, DestIP_s, DestPort_d, L4Protocol_s, PacketsDestToSrc";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        TokenCredential tokenCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId("my-client-id")
                .clientSecret("my-secret")
                .tenantId("my-tenant")
                .build();

        LogsQueryClient logsQueryClient = new LogsQueryClientBuilder()
                .credential(tokenCredential)
                .buildClient();

        LogsQueryResult queryResults = logsQueryClient.queryWorkspace("my-workspace-id", kustoQuery,
                new QueryTimeInterval(Duration.ofDays(1)));

        for (LogsTableRow row : queryResults.getTable().getRows()) {
            Date timeGenerated = sdf.parse(row.getColumnValue("TimeGenerated").get().getValueAsString());
            System.out.println(
                    new StringBuilder().
                            append("Time: ").
                            append(timeGenerated.toString()).append(", source ip: ")
                            .append(row.getColumnValue("SrcIP_s").get().getValueAsString())
                            .append(", dest ip: ")
                            .append(row.getColumnValue("DestIP_s").get().getValueAsString())
                            .append(", dest port: ")
                            .append(row.getColumnValue("DestPort_d").get().getValueAsString())
                            .append(", protocol: ")
                            .append(row.getColumnValue("L4Protocol_s").get().getValueAsString())
                            .toString());
        }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Caused by: com.azure.monitor.query.implementation.logs.models.ErrorResponseException: Status code 400, "{"error":{"message":"The request had some invalid properties","code":"BadArgumentError","correlationId":"some-id","innererror":{"code":"SemanticError","message":"A semantic error occurred.","innererror":{"code":"SEM0100","message":"'project' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'PacketsDestToSrc'"}}}}"

Same for PacketsSrcToDest, BytesDestToSrc and BytesSrcToDest.

Update:
I am using log schema version 2:
[image: log schema version 2]

any Idea why?

Comment: Are you trying to obtain the results through KQL? @Yossi

Comment: @Jahnavi Yes, as you can see in the code snippet, but apparently AzureNetworkAnalytics_CL table does not include source port and when I try one of: PacketsDestToSrc, BytesSrcToDest, BytesDestToSrc, or PacketsSrcToDest  which should be included according to the ducumentation, an error says that it cannot be resolved.

Comment: `PacketsDestToSrc` will be populated only for the version 2 log schema according to the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/traffic-analytics-schema?tabs=nsg#nsg-flow-logs-1). Which version have you enabled? @Yossi

Comment: @jahnavi, thanks for pointing this, I am using log schema 2 - I have added a screenshot to the original Q,

Comment: Have you added diagnostic settings to retrieve metrics flow? It is needed to enable all the metrics under diagnostic settings of a resource. @Yossi

Comment: And also check the discussion in the comment section of [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193490/nsg-flow-logs-dont-appear-in-azure-monitor).It is a default issue with obtaining the logs from nsg flow resource. @Yossi

Answer (score 0):

After a workaround on it, I found that the table `AzureNetworkAnalytics_CL` only contains the log information about the Azure Network security groups and firewalls. It doesn't contain information about the virtual network flow logs. And `PacketsSrcToDest` is a field which comes under virtual network flow logs but not NSG flow logs.

Refer MS Doc for [VNet flow logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/traffic-analytics-schema?tabs=nsg#vnet-flow-logs-preview-1) fields.

In order to retrieve the `PacketsSrcToDest`/`BytesDestToSrc` related data, you need to use [Azure Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/azurediagnostics#categories) with a suitable category type (Eg: Virtual Network) and for retrieving the port details use `clientPort_d` or  `port_d` in general purpose. Refer the provided Diagnostics MS Doc and obtain the log data according to your requirement.

To do so, firstly enable the virtual network flow logs by visiting the `VM/NSG` linked `VNet` as shown below.

[image]

I have also verified the `AzureNetworkAnalytics_CL` table after enabling NSG Flow logs by referring to the @TheSleepyAdmins [article](https://thesleepyadmins.com/2023/01/10/azure-network-watcher-nsg-flow-logs-review-nsg-traffic/) and was able to obtain only the NSG flow log columns as shown.

```bash
AzureNetworkAnalytics_CL
| Project TimeGenerated, FlowLogStorageAccount_s,VirtualMachine_s,PublicIPAddresses_s,VirtualSubnetwork_s
```

[image]